embedding(): argument 'indices' (position 2) must be Tensor, not ChatPromptValue
I want to add message history for my agent in langchain, and I'm following the langchain document.
LangChain - MessageHistory
import getpass
import os
from langchain_community.chat_message_histories import ChatMessageHistory
from langchain_core.chat_history import BaseChatMessageHistory
from langchain_core.runnables.history import RunnableWithMessageHistory
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain_openai.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI


os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = getpass.getpass()

llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0125")


prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        (
            "system",
            "You're an assistant who's good at {ability}. Respond in 20 words or fewer",
        ),
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history"),
        ("human", "{input}"),
    ]
)
runnable = prompt | model

store = {}

def get_session_history(session_id: str) -> BaseChatMessageHistory:
    if session_id not in store:
        store[session_id] = ChatMessageHistory()
    return store[session_id]


with_message_history = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
    runnable,
    get_session_history,
    input_messages_key="input",
    history_messages_key="history",
)

with_message_history.invoke(
    {"ability": "math", "input": "What does cosine mean?"},
    config={"configurable": {"session_id": "abc123"}},
)

When it comes to with_message_history.invoke(, I get the following error:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2235         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   2236         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 2237     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2238 
   2239 

TypeError: embedding(): argument 'indices' (position 2) must be Tensor, not ChatPromptValue

I'm running the code on the Google Colab.
Based on the document, the output should be as following:
AIMessage(content='Cosine is a trigonometric function that represents the ratio of the adjacent side to the hypotenuse of a right triangle.', response_metadata={'id': 'msg_017rAM9qrBTSdJ5i1rwhB7bT', 'model': 'claude-3-haiku-20240307', 'stop_reason': 'end_turn', 'stop_sequence': None, 'usage': {'input_tokens': 32, 'output_tokens': 31}}, id='run-65e94a5e-a804-40de-ba88-d01b6cd06864-0')

